# How to handle double pointer in C++ wrapping by Cython

Tags: c++, cython

I have a C++ object with this signature,

```
Foo(const bool* const*, const int, const float=0.025);
```

I have the corresponding a PYX file

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "foo.h":
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        Foo()
        Foo(int**, const int, const float=0.025)
        void mcq(int* &maxclique, int &sz) 

cdef class MyFoo:
    cdef Foo c_mxclik

    def __cinit__(self, int[:] b, int k, float x):
        self.c_mxclik = Foo(b,k,x)
```

which doesn't work. I don't understand how to get the `const bool* const*` part of the input from Python to the C++ code via Cython.

I'm stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `int` and `bool` and not generally the same size, so it's probably dangerous to pass an array of `int`s to a function that expects an array of `bool`s.

I'd suggest you change your Cython code to match the C++ signature. You can access the C++ `bool` in Cython with

```
from libcpp cimport bool
```

Second, you just need to take the address using the C-style `&` operator. You need to do it in two steps (i.e. first set up  a `bool*`, and then take the address of that).

```
def __cinit__(self, bool[:] b, int k, float x):
    cdef bool* b_ptr = &b[0] # address of first element
    self.c_mxclik = Foo(&b_ptr,k,x)
```

Comment: On this line   `cdef b_ptr = &b[0] # address of first element`, I get `Cannot convert 'bool *' to Python object`.

Comment: My mistake! I've hopefully fixed it. I tested it myself with a slightly simpler example and copied it across to your example wrongly

Comment: Thanks! That does it.